# Is there a limit to a JS array when building 3D shapes with WEBGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I've been trying to build a 3D character. The whole model has about 50 cube/cuboids however the shapes stop building after the 35th shape. The code is quite lengthy already but I don't know why the rest of the shapes don't show.

The js code is as follows:

```
var canvas;
var gl;

var total= 1188;

var vertex= [];

var vertexColors =[];

var indices =[];

window.onload = function init()
{
canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
gl.clearColor( 0.0,0.0,1.0, 1.0 );

gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
gl.useProgram( program );

var iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);    
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertexColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

render();
```

}

```
function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    theta[axis] += 1.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, total, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );
requestAnimFrame( render );
```

}

i've tried changing browsers and editing my code but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: the html is a pretty basic code and I know there isn't a problem with it. It's something to do with the JS but I really don't know what it is

Comment: in general I would suggest using an existing framework for working with webgl something like https://threejs.org/

Comment: we are not allowed to use any external libraries other than the few files we are given :(

Comment: then I would suggest you ask your tutor for help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `UNSIGNED_BYTE` indicies. `UNSIGNED_BYTE` can only hold values from 0 to 255 so you're can't use more than 255 vertices.

Change this line

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

to this

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

and your draw line to this

```
gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, numVertices, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
```

And you'll be able to use indices up to 65535

To use more than 65535 vertices you either need to stop using indices and instead use `gl.drawArrays` or you can check for and enable the [`OES_element_index_uint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OES_element_index_uint) extension and then use `Uint32Array` and `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` and use indicies up to 4294967296 (though there likely isn't enough memory for 4 billion vertices ）

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH SIR!!! it works perfectly!! Thank you for explaining it to me in a way I understand :D